# Vue js only loops through one element in firebase database

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Am fetching data from db using

```
setMovies(state){

            let items = [];

            db.collection('movies').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
                items = [];

                snapshot.docs.forEach((doc)=>{
                    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                    console.log(doc.data())
                    items = doc.data()
                });

                state.movies = items;

            })

        }
```

Am displaying the items using

```
<div  v-for="item in items" :key="item">
        {{ item }}<br /><br /><small >Delete</small>
        <hr />
      </div>

computed:{
      items(){
        return this.$store.getters.getMovies
      },
```

But on display it only displays one element but on the console i can see 3

Comment: Try ditching the **computed** and move `items` as a data property e.g. `data() { return { items: $store.state.movies } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each iteration of the `forEach()` you overwrite the `items` variable with `doc.data()`;

Using the [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method, as follows, should do the trick:

```
setMovies(state){

        let items = [];

        db.collection('movies').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {

            snapshot.docs.forEach((doc)=>{
                // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                console.log(doc.data())
                items.push(doc.data())
            });

            state.movies = items;

        })

 }
```